# How to fix command click code in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

First of all i'm newbie at vba, i found code that what i need but when i try to execute there is an error "Expected End Sub"

i couldn't solve where the problem is.

i'm adding "End Sub" to the end of line (it supposed to be 2 end sub i think, one is "CommandButton1_Click" one is "Copy_with_autofilter"

but there is no luck.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter1()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim FilterCriteria As String
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:AP" & LastRow(Worksheets("Data")))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria :
    'This example filter on the first column in the range (change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field 1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    'Use "<>Netherlands" as criteria if you want the opposite
    My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Akut-1"

    'If you want to filter on a cell value you can use this, use "<>" for the opposite
    'This example uses the activecell value
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & ActiveCell.Value

    'This will use the cell value from A2 as criteria
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Range("A2").Value

    ''If you want to filter on a Inputbox value use this
    'FilterCriteria = InputBox("What text do you want to filter on?", _
     '                              "Enter the filter item.")
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & FilterCriteria

    'Check if there are not more then 8192 areas(limit of areas that Excel can copy)
    CCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If CCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas:" _
             & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
             & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to worksheet"
    Else
        'Add a new Worksheet
        Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index))

        'Ask for the Worksheet name
        sheetName = "Akut-1"

        On Error Resume Next
        WSNew.Name = sheetName
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Change the name of sheet : " & WSNew.Name & _
                 " manually after the macro is ready. The sheet name" & _
                 " you fill in already exists or you use characters" & _
                 " that are not allowed in a sheet name."
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Copy/paste the visible data to the new worksheet
        My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
        With WSNew.Range("A2")
            ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
            ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Select
        End With

        ' If you want to delete the rows that you copy, also use this
        ' With My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
        '     On Error Resume Next
        '     Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
        '               .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        '     On Error GoTo 0
        '     If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
        ' End With

    End If

    'Close AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    If Not WSNew Is Nothing Then WSNew.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A2"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

End Function
```

When i click the button, it filters "Data" sheet and copies another sheet.
So i can formula the cells with filtered sheet.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, should highlight most problems immediately. Second you have 2x `End Function` at the end... you only need 1. Not sure if that's what triggers the error though.

Comment: You're also missing the `End Sub` for your `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` You can't nest `Sub`s / `Function`s

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put a sub within a sub, this cannot be done as @Tom stated in the comments. If you want the command button click to run this sub it can be done in two ways. Either you get rid of the second sub like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
etc...
```

Or you make your commandbutton call that sub directly like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Copy_With_AutoFilter1
End sub

Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter1()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
etc...
```

Please note, when you use the second option you should move the [second sub to a module](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/code-modules-event-procedures/), rather than on the sheet object you have your command button on.

I also highly recommend reading the other comments as you have a few other errors that can be easily solved.

Comment: `Call` is no longer needed to call procedures Plutian.

Comment: Hmmm, this is news to me, thank you for pointing it out @Damian, it seems like I have some reading to do. Answer amended as well.

Comment: Thank you all code worked but i need to adjust some small things.

1) i need to hide "data" sheet from the workbook, but when i hide sheet, code not working, i think i should add somewhere "ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden"

2) it creates Data2 sheet now but i need to hide it too.

Thank you again for commenting :)

Comment: @adrenalineoverdose you will massively benefit from reading [how to avoid using select, activesheet, and activeworkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). This will not only solve your issues, but also speed up your code significantly.